# Subclassing MFC CString, losing implicit conversion when CString passed to format strings (sprintf, CString::FormatString, etc.)

Tags: mfc, printf, cstring

I'm subclassing the MFC class CString (nothing wrong with the class, but trust me, I need to do this for specific implementation).  I've succesfully customized some behaviors, but I noticed that I lost the implicit (LPCTSTR) operator that seems to occur when a CString is passed into a format string.  This magic happens whether it's CString::Format or prinf/sprintf.  For example:

```
CString Str = _T("Really cool string");
TCHAR szBuffer[32];
_stprintf(szBuffer, _T("Here it is: %s"), Str);
```

I haven't figured out how this magic works with a standard CString, since CString::FormatString just passes the variable argument list through to _vswprintf and _swprintf.  But whatever it does is missing in my derived class.

The operator (LPCTSTR) is inherited as expected, and works when explicitly called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption is wrong: There is no implicit conversion to `LPCTSTR` when a `CString` object is passed to a `printf`-style function. The compiler has no way of knowing that that's what you want - it's not going to parse the format string to deduce type information.

Instead, your `CString` object is passed to `printf` **as is**. The magic here is that the `CString` authors predicted wrong assumptions about when and how the implicit cast operator is invoked and modeled `CString` to be compatible with C-strings. To do so, `CString` contains a single `LPTSTR` pointer and no v-table. Now if a `CString` object is passed to a `printf`-style function, only this pointer will wind up as a parameter, and everything appears to work. Note that appearing to work is a valid form of undefined behavior. This **is** undefined behavior.

If you're wondering where `CString` stores the remaining information (current size, capacity, etc.), it resides in memory just ahead of the character buffer. This way all the information is available through a single pointer:

```
CStringData* GetData() const throw() {
    return( reinterpret_cast< CStringData* >( m_pszData )-1 );
}
```

Now to solve your real problem: Don't rely on undefined behavior, use explicit casts where necessary and nobody will get hurt:

```
_stprintf(szBuffer, _T("Here it is: %s"), static_cast<LPCTSTR>(Str));
```

As an alternative to the cast you can call [`CString::GetString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k59cayc6.aspx):

```
_stprintf(szBuffer, _T("Here it is: %s"), Str.GetString());
```

Also keep in mind: Deriving from a class that does not provide a **virtual** destructor is a resource leak waiting to happen. In other words: Do not derive from `CString`.

Comment: Or use the function CString::GetString

Answer (score 0):

When you derive from a class, not all operators are inherited.  Google the topic of operator inheritance in C++.  In your derived class, you may need to implement the operators and simply forward to the base class.